# how to eliminate black border around the picture

Tags: android, image, border

I need to remove the black borders appears around the pictures in android screen.
My pcture are full blade but I always get a kind of black borders both in portrait or landscape orientation. I tried to change parameters but unsuccessfully.
this is my xml layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView 
android:src="@drawable/map" 
android:id="@+id/fullmap" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"> </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone help me to find the error? Pictures are bigger than the screen 480x320 - 800x480 - 1280x800

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by black border you mean the empty space around your picture left and right in landscape then you need to set [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) in you imageView Tag.

The first one will stretch the image and not preserve aspect ratio

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

this one will zoom in to the image till all the sides are filled and it preserves aspect ratio.

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: Many Thanks, I will try it soon. Does this work also with animation? I mean, I have the same picture that use animation to make a kind of zoom in and when I reach the end it has black on the left. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/closemap" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/map">
 </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: sorry this is the animation xml   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" android:fillAfter="true">
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0"
android:toAlpha="1.0" />
<scale android:fromXScale="1."
android:toXScale="1.8"
android:fromYScale="1."
android:toYScale="1.5"
android:startOffset="1500"
android:duration="2000"
/>


    
</set>